# Count rows with value and then all rows in total

Tags: mysql

I'd like to count all rows from a table where the rows belong to a user and also specifically count the rows with a specific value. For example:

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(`Status` = 5,1,0)) AS Counter_1,
SUM(IF(`Status` = 6,1,0)) AS Counter_2
FROM `Table`
WHERE `UserID` = 5";
```

And using these as:

```
$lead_count['Counter_1'];
```

However, how do I then count all of the rows that are returned regardless of their status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(`Status` = 5,1,0)) AS Counter_1,
SUM(IF(`Status` = 6,1,0)) AS Counter_2,
COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM `Table`
WHERE `UserID` = 5";
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'd tried SUM(*) which threw errors but hadn't tried COUNT(*).

Comment: `SUM(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

Although `COUNT()` is what you need, you don't need `IF()`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(`Status` = 5) AS Counter_1,
  SUM(`Status` = 6) AS Counter_2,
  COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM `Table`
WHERE `UserID` = 5;
```

`Status` = 5 is a Boolean expression that evaluates to 1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've accepted the other answer as correct as it was first, but have removed the IF statements from my code and upvoted your answer as it gives detail on a more efficient way of coding it.

Comment: @BN83 fine. You did the right thing. My answer served more as an extra.